# How can I manage Dynamic div in yii

Tags: php, yii

In my view page there is a div to get the details of persons.

View page div is:

```
<div class="text-group">  
            <ol>  
                <li>  
                    <div class="form-group">   
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'contact_name'); ?>  
<?php  echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'contact_name', array('class' => 'form-control','multiple' => true)); ?>  
                        <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'contact_name'); ?></div>   
                    </div>   
                    <div class="form-group">   
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'designation'); ?>  
<?php echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'designation', array('class' => 'form-control','multiple' => true)); ?>   
                        <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'designation'); ?></div>   
                    </div>   
                    <div class="form-group">  
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'email'); ?>  
<?php echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'email', array('class' => 'form-control','multiple' => true)); ?>  
                        <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'email'); ?></div>   
                    </div>  
                </li>  
            </ol>  
        </div>
```

and below that there is a button ADD for adding multiple contact person details when we ckick add the above div will appear once more

add button is

```
<div class="form-group">
                           <button id="btn2" class="btn-darkorange btn" type="button">add</button>
                          </div>`
```

And the javascript function is

```
   $("#btn2").click(function(){  
    $("ol").append('<li><div class="form-group">   
<label for="InputContactPerson">Contact Person</label>'+
                                       '  
 <input type="fax" class="form-control" id="InputContactPerson" >'+
                                     ' </div><div class="form-group"> <label for="InputDesignation">Designation </label>'+
                                       ' <input type="fax" class="form-control" id="InputDesignation" > </div> <div class="form-group">'+
                                      '  <label for="Email">Email</label> <input type="fax" class="form-control" id="Email" >'+
                                      '</div></li>');   
  });
```

How can I read all inputs in my controller?

Comment: Learn Stack Overflow formatting shortcodes please

Comment: what is the input field you are copying?

Comment: @kumar_v Sorry i ddnt get u.

Comment: In your js code, which html input element you are adding multiple times? `input type="fax" ` is strange for me. I saw only `input type="tel"` in html5.

Comment: k I will change that But how can i get these in my controller

Comment: But if Im trying to get $name = $_POST['InputContactPerson']; it gets error undefined variable InputContactPerson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have renderPartial function used instead of adding content through javascript....  first create an another action in controller which will handel the form... like and in that actiuon initiate your model and create a view in ur view folder for that form ... the data you want to dynamically load ... now use

```
//this can be action in your controolller
function createForm(){ 
$adscontact=new adscontact();

if(isset($_POST['adscontact']))
{
//validation and saving 
}

$this->renderPartial('_view',array('adscontact'=>$adscontact),false,true)
//here i added false as third and true as 4 param ..to use validation.
}
```

this code will help you to call that form from ur main view file.

```
//it will be in ur main view file
//ajax to call the controller
$('#btn2').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"<?php echo $this->createUrl('controllerName/createForm'); ?>",
  dataType : "html",
  success : function(response){

     $('.text-group').html(response);

  } 
  });

});
```

and the _view file will have the

```
<div class="text-group">  
        <ol>  
            <li>  
                <div class="form-group">   
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'contact_name'); ?>  
<?php  echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'contact_name', array('class' => 'form-  control','multiple' => true)); ?>  
                    <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'contact_name'); ?></div>   
                </div>   
                <div class="form-group">   
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'designation'); ?>  
<?php echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'designation', array('class' => 'form-control','multiple' => true)); ?>   
                    <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'designation'); ?></div>   
                </div>   
                <div class="form-group">  
<?php echo $form->labelEx($adscontact, 'email'); ?>  
<?php echo $form->textField($adscontact, 'email', array('class' => 'form-control','multiple' => true)); ?>  
                    <div class="errormsg"><?php echo $form->error($adscontact, 'email'); ?></div>   
                </div>  
            </li>  
        </ol>  
    </div>
```

this is the best way to do this thing ... load everytime you want to create...

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply. Now I just saw ur code. I didnt tried but I have a doubt in the controller if we are creating new object for each button click then the data will gets overwrites na??? means when I submit the form does Im able to get all those values

Comment: you have to balnk the container html to "" means like            $('.text-group').html('');  and it is safe i am using this from last three months ... and i have no problem ... it will load data from that view and it will submit the form... but if u want to submit via ajax i have also another solution for it ... and yup the view should have whole form inside it... you can also use ajax to submit form...

Comment: yes you can egt all the values clientside via js (dont do this) and also server side via submiting.. best way submit form via ajax and get saved model data array (json) into ajax response and update the view on the basis of that data

Comment: no we will create only one action for this... and if you want to update some data ... pass primary key and fetch model data for that primary key ... you will get that data in ur inputs and... updateit...

Comment: here I can add onlt one more fields. I want to add more fields. I mean wants to add n nmber of persons details

Comment: success : function(response){ $('.text-group11').html(response); } Since there specified the div which has to change its getting over write whwn I am tring to add more than one times

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47313/discussion-between-salini-and-user2542806)